# BuddyPress: Missing"Create group" button

Tags: button, buddypress

My custom Buddy Press Theme is missing the "Create a group" button. Everything else works. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

I actually think this is just something they left out in the core files.  I created a new one using hooks:

```
function groups_subnav_hook() {
    global $bp;

    $groups_link = $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->groups->slug . '/';

    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
        'name' => 'Create New Group' ,
        'slug' => 'create',
        'parent_slug' => $bp->groups->slug,
        'parent_url' => $groups_link,
        'position' => 10,
        'screen_function' => 'groups_screen_group_members',
        'user_has_access' => bp_is_my_profile() // Only the logged in user can access this on his/her profile
    ) );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'groups_subnav_hook', 2 );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'groups_subnav_hook', 2 );
```